# keyboard shortcut repeatedly stops working in xubuntu

Tags: shortcuts, xfce, xubuntu

I have and almost fresh install of xubuntu 22.04.2. I use a lot the shortcuts to move the windows around (super+arrow_key), but in this case I notice that the ones for the right and up movement didn't work.

I checked the keyboard tab inside the window manager and the shortcuts are set as expected.

[image: Window Manager]

If I edit the shortcut and enter the same key combination they start working again.
But as soon as I press the super key alone (to open the menu), these to shortcut get disabled again (left and down always work properly).

I would appreciate any pointers as to where can I look to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this.
I found a solution on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410520/super-right-for-tile-window-right-does-not-work-in-xubuntu-22-04

When opening Windows Manager, for each "Tile window" shortcu that does not work, shortcut is shown, delete it, then another appears (it looks like multiple where registered), delete it again. Then add the right one.